# Convert a raster to GeoJSON polygons in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geojson, vectorization

I'm trying to convert a raster to a polygon and export it from PostGIS as GeoJSON. Specifically I want each pixel to be a polygon with associated the raster value.

PostGIS seems to have a few different functions for converting rasters to polygons, I'm using the `ST_PixelAsPolygons` function because I want each pixel to be represented as its own polygon.

Example:

```
SELECT ST_PixelAsPolygon(rast) FROM tbl;
```

However this returns a set of records for each raster and I can't easily convert this to GeoJSON.

Does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the example on the man page for [ST_PixelAsPolygons](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_PixelAsPolygons.html) you will see how you can access the geometries using `table_alias.geom` syntax (similar in spirit to how ST_Dump works to turn a set or records into individual rows). Following on from that example, you can pass `(gv).geom` to the [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) function, eg,

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON((gv).geom) 
  FROM 
      (SELECT ST_PixelAsPolygons(
          ST_SetValue(
              ST_SetValue(
                  ST_AddBand(
                    ST_MakeEmptyRaster(2, 2, 0, 0, 0.001, -0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 4269), 
                                       '8BUI'::text, 1, 0), 
                    2, 2, 10), 
            1, 1, NULL)
     ) gv 
 ) foo;
```

which will return the three rows:

> {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0.001,0.001],[0.002,0.002],[0.003,0.001],[0.002,0],[0.001,0.001]]]}
>
> {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0.001,-0.001],[0.002,0],[0.003,-0.001],[0.002,-0.002],[0.001,-0.001]]]}
>
> {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0.002,0],[0.003,0.001],[0.004,0],[0.003,-0.001],[0.002,0]]]}

If you wish to turn this into a FeatureCollection, you can use a combination of **row_to_json**, **array_agg** and **array_to_json** to group the rows together into an array and add in the *"type":"FeatureCollection"* before the features array. The general idea is that you select the 'Feature', the GeoJSON representation of the geometry and the properties in one subquery, and then use **array_to_json** and **array_agg** to group this into an array of features, with *'FeatureCollection' as type* before the array. Finally, you select **row_to_json** to group this all together inside {}.

**Note** you have to do the nasty subselect on the properties -- in your case the raster pixel values -- to avoid the labels being f1, f2, etc. See this [Postgres Online](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html) article for more information.

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) 
  FROM 
    (SELECT 'FeatureCollection' as type, array_to_json(array_agg(feats)) as features 
      FROM 
         (SELECT 'Feature' as type, 
                 st_asgeojson((gv).geom)::json as geometry, 
                 row_to_json((SELECT props FROM (SELECT (gv).val as value) as props )) as properties  
            FROM 
                (SELECT 
                    ST_PixelAsPolygons(
                       ST_SetValue(
                         ST_SetValue(
                             ST_AddBand(
                                 ST_MakeEmptyRaster(2, 2, 0, 0, 0.001, -0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 4269), 
                            '8BUI'::text, 1, 0),
                        2, 2, 10), 
                     1, 1, NULL)
               ) gv 
          ) json
    ) feats 
) fc;
```

which now produces:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", 
     "features":[
           {"type":"Feature",
                "geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0.001,0.001],[0.002,0.002],[0.003,0.001],[0.002,0],[0.001,0.001]]]},
                "properties":{"value":1}
           },
           {"type":"Feature",
                "geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0.001,-0.001],[0.002,0],[0.003,-0.001],[0.002,-0.002],[0.001,-0.001]]]},
                "properties":{"value":1}
            },
            {"type":"Feature",
                "geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0.002,0],[0.003,0.001],[0.004,0],[0.003,-0.001],[0.002,0]]]},
                "properties":{"value":10}
            }
     ]
}
```

**Note:** You need to cast the ST_AsGeoJSON to JSON, with the :: operator, or else you will end up with all the quotes being escaped, as \" in the output.

Comment: Did I miss the point of your question? I realize that this is perhaps, not simple, but I believe it answers the question?

Comment: OK, I did miss something. I have edited the post which now includes the pixel values as a property of the output GeoJSON. Obviously, the whole inner select making a dummy raster would be replaced with a straight call to ST_PixelAsPolygons in your case.

Comment: I have looked at the solution you provided (thanks by the way). [Here](https://pastebin.com/5UNtTcqZ) I have pasted the query I want to run. I need all the pixels from a raster that intersects a polygon in another table. The query works but I get to many polygons in the GeoJSON. I have posted an image where I've outlined the polygon queried in the nested select clause, find it [here](https://imgur.com/a/ipHYz). I would be greatful for any advice, even though it's not really related to the original question.

Comment: OK, you should probably accept this answer and ask another question :-). However, the function [ST_Reclass](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Reclass.html) allows you to use banding, so that when you convert rasters to polygons you don't get so many.